# Windows User Mode Scheduler (UMS) Retired?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, scheduler, usermode

I just came around the following [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelcppnative/thread/afee813b-0dd9-498c-98c1-c996169099f6) which seems to say that the user mode scheduler which was introduced with Windows 7 is (going to be) retired?

> *Don McCrady, Microsoft:* As you may know from reading other forum entries here, the UMS scheduler is being retired, and eventually choosing UmsThreadDefault will just end up using the Win32 thread scheduler.

Does anyone have any more information regarding this? Why is it being retired, was it to buggy or is it replaced with something else? I haven't found any other references to this.